# How to set custom IP for Solr server from Docker compose file?

Tags: docker, solr, ip

**In short:**

I have a hard time figuring out how to set custom IP for a Solr container from the docker-compose.yml file.

**Detailed**

We want to deploy local dev environments, for Drupal instances, via Docker.

The propblem is, that while from the browser I can access the Solr server via the "traditional" `http://localhost:8983/solr`, Drupal cannot connect to it this way. The internal 0.0.0.0, and 127.0.0.1 doesn't work either. The only way Drupal can connect to the Solr server is via lan IP, which differs for every station obviously, and since the configuration in Drupal needs to be updated anyway, I thought that specifying a custom IP on which they can communicate would be my best choice, but it's not straightforward.

I am aware that assigning static IP to the container is not the best solution, but it seems more feasible than tinkering with [solr.in.sh](http://shal.in/post/127561227271/how-to-make-apache-solr-listen-on-a-specific-ip), and if someone has a different approach to achieve this, I am opened to solutions.

Most likely I could use some command line parameter along with `docker run`, but we need to run the containers with `docker-compose up -d`, so this wouldn't be an optimal solution.

Ideal would be a Solr container section example for the compose file. Thanks.

**Note:**
[This link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/ipv4address-ipv6address) shows an example how to set it, but I can't understand it well. Please keep in mind that I am by no means an expert.

Forgot to mention that the host is based on `Linux`, mostly `Ubuntu` and `Debian`.

**Edit:**

As requested, here is my compose file:

```
version: "2"

services:
  db:
    image: wodby/drupal-mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
#    command: --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci # The simple way to override the mariadb config.
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker-runtime/mariadb-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d # Place init .sql file(s) here.

  php:
    image: wodby/drupal-php:7.0 # Allowed: 7.0, 5.6.
    environment:
      DEPLOY_ENV: dev
      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S mailhog:1025
      PHP_XDEBUG_ENABLED: 1 # Set 1 to enable.
#      PHP_SITE_NAME: dev
#      PHP_HOST_NAME: localhost:8000
#      PHP_DOCROOT: public # Relative path inside the /var/www/html/ directory.
#      PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S mailhog:1025
      # PHP_XDEBUG_ENABLED: 1
      # PHP_XDEBUG_AUTOSTART: 1
      # PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_CONNECT_BACK: 0         # This is needed to respect remote.host setting bellow
      # PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST: "10.254.254.254"  # You will also need to 'sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 10.254.254.254'
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./docroot:/var/www/html

  nginx:
    image: wodby/drupal-nginx
    hostname: testing
    environment:
#      NGINX_SERVER_NAME: localhost
      NGINX_UPSTREAM_NAME: php
#      NGINX_DOCROOT: public # Relative path inside the /var/www/html/ directory.
      DRUPAL_VERSION: 7 # Allowed: 7, 8.
    volumes_from:
      - php
    ports:
      - "${PORT_WEB}:80"

  pma:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      PMA_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - '${PORT_PMA}:80'
    links:
      - db

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    ports:
      - "8002:8025"

  redis:
    image: redis:3.2-alpine

#  memcached:
#    image: memcached:1.4-alpine

#  memcached-admin:
#    image: phynias/phpmemcachedadmin
#    ports:
#      - "8006:80"

  solr:
    image: makuk66/docker-solr:4.10.3
    volumes:
      - ./docker-runtime/solr:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores
#    entrypoint:
#      - docker-entrypoint.sh
#      - solr-precreate
    ports:
      - "8983:8983"

#  varnish:
#    image: wodby/drupal-varnish
#    depends_on:
#      - nginx
#    environment:
#      VARNISH_SECRET: secret
#      VARNISH_BACKEND_HOST: nginx
#      VARNISH_BACKEND_PORT: 80
#      VARNISH_MEMORY_SIZE: 256M
#      VARNISH_STORAGE_SIZE: 1024M
#    ports:
#      - "8004:6081" # HTTP Proxy
#      - "8005:6082" # Control terminal

#  sshd:
#    image: wodby/drupal-sshd
#    environment:
#      SSH_PUB_KEY: "ssh-rsa ..."
#    volumes_from:
#      - php
#    ports:
#      - "8006:22"
```

Comment: You'll have more luck posting your compose file without the static IP, then we could show you how to add the docker networking.

Comment: I've managed to create a network interface based on the official documentation, but my Solr server wasn't exposed on the desired IP address, remaining on 0.0.0.0. I've left it out from the compose file, since it's the same as in the docs, and not worked as expected.

Comment: Is the Solr server also running inside a docker container? Edit...Nm I see it in the docker-compose...

Answer (score 0):

A docker run example would be

```
IP_ADDRESS=$(hostname -I)
docker run -d -p 8983:8983 solr bin/solr start -h ${IP_ADDRESS} -p 8983
```

Comment: Hi Nhol, thank you for your suggestion. I've edited the question to include my compose file. Docker run would be a solution, but not preferred. I keep it under radar, if there will be no other options, I'll take into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning static IPs, you could use the following method to get the container's IP dynamically.

When you link containers together, they share there network information (IP, port) to each other. The information is stored in each container as environmental variables.

#### Example

*docker-compose.yml*

```
service:
  build: .
  links:
    - redis
  ports:
    - "3001:3001"
redis:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "6369:6369"
```

The service container will now have the following environmental variables:

**Dynamic IP Address Stored Within "service" container:**
REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR

**Dynamic PORT Stored Within "service" container:**
REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT

You can always check this out by shelling into the container and looking yourself.

```
docker exec -it [ContainerID] bash
printenv
```

[image: printenv]

Inside your nodeJS app you can use the environmental variable in your connection function by using *process.env*.

```
let client = redis.createClient({   
       port: process.env.REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR, 
       host: process.env.REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT
});
```

### *Edit*

Here is the updated docker-compose.yml "solr" section:

```
  solr:
    image: makuk66/docker-solr:4.10.3
    volumes:
      - ./docker-runtime/solr:/opt/solr/server/solr/mycores
    entrypoint:
      - docker-entrypoint.sh
      - solr-precreate
    ports:
       - "8983:8983"
    links:
       - db
```

In the above example the "solr" container is now linked with the "db" container. this is done using the "links" field.

You can do the same thing if you wanted to link the solr container to any other container within the docker-compose.yml file.

The db containers information will now be available to the solr container (via the enviromental variables I mentioned earlier).

Without the linking, you will not see those enviromental variables listed when you do the *printenv* command.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately `printenv` in the Solr container doesn't reveal any environmental variable related to the IP. Didn't know about printenv, and it's certainly helpful, but for Solr, it seems, doesn't do much. Thank  you tho.

Comment: Are the containers "linked" together?

Comment: I just looked at your "solr" docker-compose section and there is no link specified. You need to specify the link... Ill update the answer to include what it should be.

Comment: I resolved this issue by creating my small app_net network and assigning a specific static ipv4_address to the solr. Let me know if there are better ways since i am new to docker world :) Thanks!